# What is the essential difference between docker and rkt?

Tags: docker, containers, coreos, rkt

How are they functioning differently?
Which features of the kernel are they using?

Comment: Have you already looked at this [CoreOS blog post](https://coreos.com/blog/rocket/), *Why we are building rkt* section is probably a good place to start your search?

Comment: The blog post you've attached is almost 2 years old, I think linking to more up-to-date sources can give more relevant information, especially when looking at the recent developments in the container wars, like this one - http://thenewstack.io/docker-fork-talk-split-now-table/

Comment: And you think an recent article that sites no sources about what may or may not happen is more useful than a blog post from the company that created the tool about why they created it?

Comment: 1. cites, not sites. 2. The recent article cites multiple sources, but still isn't a proper answer in my mind. See my answer below - which answers best to @NeoWang's question, IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read all about it in this [link](https://coreos.com/rkt/docs/latest/rkt-vs-other-projects.html)

Basically, my impression is that rkt takes pride in being image-agnostic (meaning you can run images that were built using docker or other container engines) and contain less overhead than docker does. This is a nice picture to describe the differences between the two (taken from the link I've attached) - 
[image]